# Find/Children vs descendant selector jquery performance differences

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

I am trying to understand why one of the snippets in [this jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-caching-find-methods2/2) seems to be significantly slower than the others.

These are the four snippets:

```
$(".menu-vertical li.selected > ul.static").show().parents().show();

$('ul.root').find('li.selected').children('ul.static').show().parents().show();

$("ul.root li.selected > ul.static").show().parents().show();

$('ul.root li.selected').children('ul.static').show().parents().show();
```

The second one seems to be consistently slower in all browsers and I don't understand why.

Comment: I have given two examples for performance 1) find() vs Direct Child(>) selectors vs Child selector Perfomance test 1 [http://jsperf.com/jquery-child-selector-vs-find/2][link1] 2) find() vs Descendant selectors vs Child selector Perfomance test 2 [http://jsperf.com/jquery-child-selector-vs-find/9][link2] [link1]: http://jsperf.com/jquery-child-selector-vs-find/2 [link2]: http://jsperf.com/jquery-child-selector-vs-find/9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What makes the second to be different from the others?

```
$('ul.root')               // you get the collection of all `ul.root`
    .find('li.selected')   // in each collection you search for `li.selected`
    .children('ul.static') // you get `ul.static` children elements of each found
    ...
```

Note how many iterations you need to make. In all other examples most of search is performed in a single query, which is evaluated many times faster.

Comment: would there be a more efficient way to get the same results while using find? (or to reform my question, why use find afterall since it's slower?)

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos Often single selector performs faster. However, in some cases `find` could be a silver bullet. So, my answer: it depends.

Comment: After browsing many similar questions here it seems benchmarking with hypothetical scenarios doesn't help much as results differ based on HTML, browser, machine etc..

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos Exactly so.

Answer (score 0):

The number of children matters.

With many(say >10) children `$el.find('> selector')` performs better

With a few children `$el.children('selector')` performs better.

It is because children() iterates over all children to test the given selector.